# How can I stop people using Gamemodes to cheat and instead give them an achievement for trying?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft, I am making a map in which there may be hardish parts. Currently, they're allowed to cheat using */gamemode*, but I want to make it so that they can't.  They also get an achievement for trying to cheat.

Basically, I am asking for a series of 3 commands I can run in an infinite loop, which runs 3 command blocks, that will, in order:

1. Check for if the player/one of the players is cheating.
2. Tell them they've been cheating and give them an achievement.
3. Change their gamemode back to Adventure mode.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: I've tried looking all over for an answer, but no-one has it already asked and answered. That's why I came here.

Comment: Chances are good you won't find a complete solution to this in one go.  So break it down into parts, and focus on each piece.  See what you can find for each section.  Asking us to do it all for you is generally not well received by the community.

Comment: `@a[m=!adventure]` will select all players that are not in adventure mode. The `advancement` command can grant advancements, and the `gamemode` command can change gamemodes. That really should be all you need, and it's all listed on the wiki.

Comment: Thanks! But now I have to give myself something to break the loop :I I tried to test it.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Try using commands to delete the command block. In future, you can add an exception (`@a[m=!adventure,tag=!admin]`) for people with a special tag, then give yourself that tag.

Comment: How do I give myself that tag, Ajax? I'm not good at commands :|

Comment: `scoreboard players tag <target> add admin`

Comment: Now I need to find out how to make it so that the _/tellraw_ ,which is what I used for the achievement, only runs if the command block has to change anyone's gamemode.

Comment: Anyone here know?

Comment: Hello? Anyone have the knowledge that I require? Or do I have to make a new question?

Comment: Be patient. People will answer when they do. We are volunteers, so there is no time limit as to when someone can or will answer.

Comment: We don't edit our questions to include Resolved, or anything like that. You can delete the question, if you like, but otherwise, it exists to help future readers as well.

Comment: Ok then. Are these automated messages, or...

Comment: You need to use a chain command block and set it to be conditional. That way it only executes when the previous command was successful. And changing back the gamemode should be the last thing you do, since the gamemode distinguishes cheating players from non-cheating players.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the selector `@a[gamemode=creative]` to detect all players in creative mode.

But if you allow players access to commands, you can't guarantee for anything. They could just use `/setblock` to replace the command block detecting their gamemode change or do something else against it. There are ways to prevent that, but you're very quickly getting into an endless game of cat and mouse to prevent every possible way they could tamper with your system. That can be fun (I'm planning to do such a thing in the future), but it's certainly not what you want in this case. Better just disallow commands for everyone.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `@a[gamemode=creative]`

Comment: That's right, it changed in 1.13, thanks for telling me. Updating my answers to 1.13 is still on my todo list, but only for answers with score of 2 or more, since otherwise I would have to check 239 answers.